# URL or Link Encoding

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, url-encoding

Hello guys,

```
<object id="flashstream" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="768" height="450" __idm_id__="34363393">
    <param name="movie" value="http://static.viooz.co/07/player.swf">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
      <param name="FlashVars" value="plugins=http://static.viooz.co/07/plugins/proxy.swf&amp;proxy.link=viooz*401717b4c50d526fb6a6cc19150c106efd2030858dacb96833e3690d09369eec40d561b2d6ff2211961bf69bc37d82c200d1716062f0d70f2a8c901d0fd20297e9a2db13edadca0fbc0006d668a4f2b1f153d4fbb20dff07ade9d14aeb479513&amp;proxy.image=http://static.viooz.co/images/movies/0770828.jpg">
    <embed name="flashstream" src="http://static.viooz.co/07/player.swf" flashvars="plugins=http://static.viooz.co/07/plugins/proxy.swf&amp;proxy.link=viooz*401717b4c50d526fb6a6cc19150c106efd2030858dacb96833e3690d09369eec40d561b2d6ff2211961bf69bc37d82c200d1716062f0d70f2a8c901d0fd20297e9a2db13edadca0fbc0006d668a4f2b1f153d4fbb20dff07ade9d14aeb479513&amp;proxy.image=http://static.viooz.co/images/movies/0770828.jpg" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" width="768" height="450" __idm_id__="34363394">
    </object>
```

I am looking for Encoding type of the link in above example. A link is encoded to `viooz*401717b4c50d526fb6a6cc19150c106efd2030858dacb96833e3690d09369eec40d561b2d6ff2211961bf69bc37d82c200d1716062f0d70f2a8c901d0fd20297e9a2db13edadca0fbc0006d668a4f2b1f153d4fbb20dff07ade9d14aeb479513` Any idea which encoding are they using? I have tried base32 and base64 encoding but this is something different.

Thanks very much for your help.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they don't want you to find...
Thats not base32 \ base 64, more like a custom encryption so u'll never find out the real link..

Comment: Well! I actually do know the real links but I want to use this encryption in my own site to secure my links like them that's why I am trying to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have decoded, Actually this was just for learning purpose to decode encryption.

anyways above encoded string is decoded to (https://picasaweb.google.com/107085901016310715708/0770828HdMp4?authkey=Gv1sRgCIDV4qumxbrYSw)

Comment: Hey i also want to use same encryption in my site. Will you plz help me for that? How you decode that?

Comment: How did you arrive at this?

Comment: @daleyjem this link was encoded using gkplugin with a custom key. Finding that custom key is difficult but not impossible. As i have mentioned it was just for a learning purpose, so I didn't follow it after.